# How to type annotate MobX observable objects using non-OOP approach?

Tags: typescript, mobx

Please, consider this example:

```
import { observable } from "mobx";

interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const obj1 = { namee: "Uldis", age: "35" };

type MyObjectObservable = ???;

const obj1Observable: MyObjectObservable = observable(obj1); // I want to have compiler error here

function doStuff(obj: MyObjectObservable) {}

doStuff({ name: "Uldis", age: 35 }) // I want to have compiler error here because passed object is not an observable
```

How should type for `MyObjectObservable` be defined? I want to have as strict types as possible and I don't want to use OOP approach because of other type related issues such as not having precise subtypes for the state that methods use.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no error in Typescript when using `observable` or `makeObservable`

This is all valid code:

```
import { makeAutoObservable, observable } from "mobx"

interface MyObject {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const obj1 = { name: "Uldis", age: 35 }

const make: MyObject = makeAutoObservable(obj1)
const obj1Observable: MyObject = observable(obj1)

function doStuff(obj: MyObject) {}

doStuff({ name: "Uldis", age: 35 })
doStuff(make)
doStuff(obj1Observable)
```

Comment: I want it to not compile for cases when a plain object is passed to a function which expects an observable. It might have a `reaction` call inside or some other mobx specific thing which wouldn't work with plain non-observable objects. I see that type is `makeObservable<T extends object, AdditionalKeys extends PropertyKey = never>(target: T, annotations?: AnnotationsMap<T, NoInfer<AdditionalKeys>>, options?: CreateObservableOptions): T;` which is in line wit your answer, but it's not what I'm looking for. I might create a custom type to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

1. Use boxed observable

```js
import { observable, IObservableValue } from "mobx";

interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const obj1 = { namee: "Uldis", age: "35" };

type MyObjectObservable = IObservableValue<MyObject>;

const obj1Observable: MyObjectObservable = observable.box(obj1);

obj1Observable.get(); // returns MyObject
```

2. Add your own branded `Observable` type in order to avoid wrapping with an additional object.

```js
//customObservable.ts

import {observable as observableImpl} from 'mobx'

const mobx = Symbol('mobx');
export type Observable<T> = T & { [K in typeof mobx]: never };

export const observable = <T extends object>(obj: T): Observable<T> => {
  return observableImpl(obj) as Observable<T>;
};
```

```js
import { observable, Observable } from "./customObservable";
import { observable as originalObservable} from "mobx";

interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const obj1 = { namee: "Uldis", age: "35" };

type MyObjectObservable = Observable<MyObject>;

const obj1Observable: MyObjectObservable = observable(obj1);
const obj2Observable: MyObjectObservable = originalObservable(obj1); // compile-time error

obj1Observable.name; //string
obj1Observable.age;  //number
```

Comment: I prefer solution no.2. With a minor adjustment it works: `export type Observable<T> = T & { [mobx]: never };`. I assumed MobX would provide some generic type to achieve this, but great portion of implementations use OOP approach where this particular problem is not observed.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this more closely I've came up with this solution:

```
import { makeObservable,IObservableValue } from "mobx"

type MyObservable=IObservableValue<{name:string}>

const obj = makeMyObservable({ name:'Johny' })
const obj2 = {name:'Johny'}

function makeMyObservable<T extends Record<string,any>>(val:T){

    return makeObservable(val) as unknown as IObservableValue<T>
}

function onlyMyObservable(val:MyObservable){
    return val
}

onlyMyObservable(obj)
onlyMyObservable(obj2) // error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbziAhgawKYHkBGBnDKANxRwBsMAaASVwONIoDUUyBXDOAXzgDMoIIOACIQEHAA9hAKGkwAnmE4BZeXUIlyGALy18GxhhbsMAHgQA7FCAwAuPDCjALAcy4A+WQGMIFh3HEAKzhtZHQMVXUGLQAKJCsbWwByACkIAAsLeSTuAEppHz94IIAmEMQEu1SMrKSuWV42Cy8YYF8wzEj9aIpTABU4DAkYDAsAEzw4ACUMHygx0wcnV0oULPd3GJIyWz7chFk4I7goDBg2KAsO7G7NCi3WXLgUSaa0CwgAdyuXuD16O5GVgcfqeerSRrNVrtXxkeRdAGGB47BEGLT7aTHE5nC5XbbScGw+FqW5IoL5ImonoYGKlJ4AenpgygAig0iAA)